# Fetching videos infos Youtube (Sometimes forbidden for some videos)

Tags: php, video, youtube, youtube-api

I have a problem, I am developing a website where people can share YouTube videos and sometimes, I get an error for some videos (not all of them) where YouTube return this : failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden

I would like to know if there is a maximum-number-requests-per-hour for example for fetching videos ?
I am using this address to fetch infos : http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q={VIDEO_ID}

And there is my code :

```
<?php   
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, YT_API_URL . $post->get_youtubeVideo());
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
//$feed holds a rss feed xml returned by youtube API
$feed = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

//Using SimpleXML to parse youtube's feed
$xml = simplexml_load_string($feed);

$entry = $xml->entry[0];
//If no entry whas found, then youtube didn't find any video with specified id
if($entry) {
    $media = $entry->children('media', true);
    $group = $media->group;

    $title = $group->title;
    $desc = $group->description;
    $thumb = $group->thumbnail[0];
    list($thumb_url, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $thumb_time) = $thumb->attributes();
    $content_attributes = $group->content->attributes();

    echo '<div class="youtube-video-inpost group" data-video-id="'.$post->get_youtubeVideo().'">
        <div class="thumbnail"><div class="play-button"></div><img src="https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/'.$post->get_youtubeVideo().'/mqdefault.jpg" width="195" height="110" /></div>
        <div class="infos">
            <div class="title"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='.$post->get_youtubeVideo().'" target="_blank" class="link-dark">'.$title.'</a></div>
            <div class="description">'.$desc.'</div>
        </div>
    </div>';
}
```

?>

Can someone help me please ?
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Yes, there is a "maximum-number of requests". It's called quota. Once this limit is exceeded, you'll not be able to do any further requests on this day. However - this is not what we're looking for here! You'd receive error stating: `quotaLimitExceeded` in it's response body.

`403 Forbidden` tells us that the requested resource (`the video`) **is not public** visible!
Probably it's `private`. You should handle this and tell your users that videos need to be public!

#### Code improvements

I strongly suggest using [Googles API PHP client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) if you're unable to do the requests properly without it! Your code contains problems:

- You aren't authenticated -> **quota limit is exceeding faster**
- You won't get detailed usage statistics
- And prolly much more bad smells.